# Add a JavaScript function for all rows in a Datatables grid

Tags: javascript, datatable

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});

function do_ok() {
  document.getElementById("a3").checked = true;
}

function do_error() {
  document.getElementById("a12").checked = true;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- DataTables -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Include</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A01</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="a1" value="4" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A02</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="a2" value="25" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A03</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="a3" value="100" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A04</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="a4" value="99" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A05</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="a5" value="88" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A06</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="a6" value="38" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A07</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="a7" value="57" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A08</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="a8" value="46" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A09</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="a9" value="42" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A10</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="a10" value="28" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A11</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="a11" value="43" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A12</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="a12" value="125" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button onclick="do_ok()">Click Me(OK)</button>
  <button onclick="do_error()">Click Me(Row 12)</button>

  <!-- DataTables -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Unless I show above 25 rows per page, when I click button 'Click Me(Row 12)', a JavaScript error occurs since the table shows only 10 rows per page by default.

Any idea how to tick row 12's checkbox without editing maximum rows per page?

I have 5000+ rows in actual, I don't want show them all to make the JavaScript  work.

Comment: can you switch to that page where a12 is and then try checked=true @John

Comment: @ShubhamSingla Of course I can. However, I have 5000+ rows in actual, I don't want user show 4000th rows or switch to that 4000th rows page to checked = true.

Comment: I think these articles outlines the intended data driven way to work with checkbox columns: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/api/checkbox.html and https://datatables.net/blog/2014-09-09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can help, but you need to make it fit for your solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Common function to update checkboxes
    function updateCheckBox(){

    // Use jQuery to set property so that
    // on not found element it fails silenty
    // and continue to next
    $("#a3").prop('checked',true);
    $("#a12").prop('checked',true)
  }

  // Initialize DataTable with event on 'draw' to
  // update checkboxes
  $('#example').DataTable().on('draw.dt', updateCheckBox);

  // Initial checkbox status
  updateCheckBox();

});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjowwayn/)

Comment: I think I'm getting closer rofl. Let say function updateCheckBox is with parameter, can you help with that? I just updated your JsFiddle. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I guess  you want buttons to be working, [here you go](https://jsfiddle.net/AmitKB/sjowwayn/3/)

Comment: Successfully saved my day ;) Thank you

Comment: Please test it well before applying to production